# std::cout not working after the declaration and definition of vector of structure c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Why is this `cout` in the main function is not printing anything? If I add `cout` before the vector of structure declaration then it works fine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct process
{
  int id;
  int at;
  int bt;
};


int main()
{
  int p = 3;
  vector<process> dataframe;
  dataframe[0].id = 1;
  dataframe[0].at = 0;
  dataframe[0].bt = 3;

 dataframe[0].id = 2;
 dataframe[0].at = 2;
 dataframe[0].bt = 4;

 dataframe[0].id = 3;
 dataframe[0].at = 5;
 dataframe[0].bt = 6;

 cout << "TEsT jhij " << endl;   //Why is this cout not working?

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vector<process> dataframe` is of size 0. indexing 1st element is out of bounds and it's UB. Take a look at [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) for adding elements to the vector.

Comment: Currently the size of your vector is zero, and you are accessing indices of elements that don't exist yet, hence there will be a segmentation fault. You can either push back the elements in to the vector or reserve space by adding `dataframe.reserve(3)` after the declaration of the vector.

Comment: After C++11 you can pass the initial size to the constructor if you know how many there will be.  See constructor #4 at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah being able to construct a vector with an initial size has been possible via constructor #3 since before C++11

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry. I just read the page wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You create a vector, automatically allocated on the stack.
Then, you try to set elements of this vector by accessing out of bounds indexes.
You may be overwriting anything anywhere.
You could try to use https://godbolt.org/ to see what code is generated and understand why nothing is printed.

Comment: You need to expand on why it is empty, that the default constructor for a `std::vector` does not allocate any storage for it's backing buffer.

Comment: @user4581301 actually it could. It is implementation-dependent. And, here, I'm not sure if the vector could be optimized out or not given that it is not read. Hence my advice to look at the generated code. It's difficult to describe precisely UB.

Comment: You've got me there. All the Standard says is [Constructs an empty `vector`, using the specified allocator.](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#cons-1). I've never seen a `vector` implementation waste time allocating storage until it was forced to, but we could easily have a Short Vector Optimization trick in play.